# VB.NET Cookies in HTTPWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, cookies, web, login-script

Alright, I've taken a look around stack overflow and I haven't found anything that 100% answers the issue I am having.. I am currently making an auto-login for a site known as e926.net and I have an issue with the way that they handle their login.

Updated Question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200801/httpwebrequest-cookies-and-authorization-tokens) Note: There is still important information on this question.

Right now I am using this code:

```
Sub Client()
    Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim responseReader As StreamReader
    Dim responseData As String
    Dim postData As String = "authenticity_token=ubL5PfTzyrvhB%2Bb1A2MISb2IUZxsEadmZWc0z7Gs2qA%3D&url=&user%5Bname%5D=USERNAME&user%5Bpassword%5D=PASSWORD&user%5Broaming%5D=0"
    Dim cookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    Dim requestWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim strUrl As String = Nothing
    Dim strRequestedHTML As String

    Try
        'get login  page with cookies
        strUrl = "https://e926.net/user/login"
        webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl)
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies

        'recieve non-authenticated cookie
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close()

        'post form  data to page
        strUrl = "https://e926.net/user/authenticate"
        webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl)
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        'webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
        webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length

        requestWriter = New StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream)
        requestWriter.Write(postData)
        requestWriter.Close()

        'recieve authenticated cookie
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close()

        'now we get the authenticated page
        webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://e926.net/post")
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies
        responseReader = New StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream())
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
        responseReader.Close()
        strRequestedHTML = responseData
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(strRequestedHTML)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("<br />There was an error  going to this site: " + strUrl + "<br> Error: " + ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

That code was found and modified from another site that I unfortunately forgot the link to, but it has worked fine on the first 5 sites I tried it on.. However since E926 works by getting the details from the 'login' page and then redirecting to the 'authentication' page it seems like the program isn't transferring the cookies properly to allow the information from 'login' to be transferred. I've been looking at 'fiddler 2' to get an idea of what the 'cookies' and the information looks like that is actually sent to the pages, and it seems clear that the cookies are missing.. I have double checked the 'authentication token' and it never seems to change as far as I've seen, but it is given on the 'login' page from a hidden form.

So my question is, how might I transfer the cookies to allow the login process to happen properly, and is that my issue or is something else causing the problem?

Edit:
Headers from IE: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UPf2vzPF11Q-i_3xSkZmdN1dfqFZX4ydyAZhVeQlh94/edit?usp=sharing

Headers from program/that code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ltZo3JZLt4sZiwZBltfqqParb3H86qi62I0KZN5t_VE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Side note: Their login system is _completely_ insecure.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought that a few times which is why when I have to work with that site at all, I use a dated password and username.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment `webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies` so that you actually send and receive cookies from the login request.

Comment: Haha, that was actually part of my debugging, I forgot to uncomment it.. It still doesn't work with it uncommented however. My apologies for having missed that little detail.

Comment: @user2994429: With that uncommented, what do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: These are the proper headers: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UPf2vzPF11Q-i_3xSkZmdN1dfqFZX4ydyAZhVeQlh94/edit?usp=sharing

These are what I am getting: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ltZo3JZLt4sZiwZBltfqqParb3H86qi62I0KZN5t_VE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Their server probably wants a User-Agent.

Comment: Aaah right, I forgot that I had removed that from the old code I had.. I'll try that real quick.

Comment: No cigar, I tried it and I ended up with the same headers as before.. Which as I said, the other sites were accepting this code but they had a simpler login process.